# ZendFramework2: Is it possible to get global.php config into a model without serviceLocator?

Tags: php, events, zend-framework2, service-locator

In config/autoload/global.php I have only the config for my database.
In my model I have:

```
public function __construct($adapter = null)
    {
        if ($adapter) {
            $this->adapter = $adapter;
        } else {
            ... //here I need to get the config without serviceLocator  
        }
    }
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $events->getSharedManager();
        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach("*", "redirect", array($this, "onRedirect"));
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener)
        {
            if ($events->detach($listener))
            {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onRedirect(EventInterface $e)
    {
        ...
    }
```

The reason is simple. I am trying to add something into the database when an event is triggered and I can't get serviceLocator on the listener. I don't know why.

So... is is possible to get the config file without serviceLocator?

Comment: I would rather try to find the reason why you cannot get `ServiceLocator` inside your listener. This should be possible. With your question you are not solving the actual problem. Can you post more details on why you cannot get your `ServiceLocator` inside the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the `ServiceLocator` inside your listener through a factory like in any other service:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Listener\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Listener\SomeListener;

/**
 * Factory for creating the listener
 */
class SomeListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * Create SomeListener
     *
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @return SomeListener
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');
        $adapter = // create adapter using config and use it to create your listener
        return new SomeListener($adapter);
    }
}
```

Register your listener factory inside your `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Listener\SomeListener' => 'Application\Listener\Factory\SomeListenerFactory',
    )
)
```

Now you can get your listener from service manager anywhere you want:

```
$someListener = $serviceManager->get('Application\Listener\SomeListener');
```

---

If you really want config inside your class (I don't see any reason why this would be necessary and it is against ZF2 principles) you could include your config file:

Your `global.config.php` file

```
<?php
return array(
    'key' => 'value'
);
```

You can simply fetch the contents using php include:

```
function fetchConfig()
{
    include("path/to/global.config.php");
}
```